# Data only correctly updates when step through

Tags: android, json, api, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Currently when I run the application the recycler view shows data when logged in. When the application is recompiled and run again but logged in with a different person, the previous persons data is shown.

This is even after API token calls are made. However when using the debugger and stepping through, the debugger shows the correct information and when I just run through the whole thing the application shows the correct information.

Seems like I have to step through the debugger for my application to show the correct data.

Here is the fragment.

```
public class allFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView usersListView;


ArrayList<MessageData> arrMessageData; //= new ArrayList<MessageData>();


allRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

ProgressDialog pd;


public allFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Load().execute(null, null, null);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

    usersListView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.allListView);


    pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading messages",
            "Loading...", true);

    //new Load().execute(null, null, null);

    refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Your code to refresh the list here.
            // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
            // once the network request has completed successfully.
            new Load().execute(null, null, null);
        }
    });



    return rootView;

}

class Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd;

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor()).addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()).build();



        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String auth_token_string = settings.getString("token", ""/*default value*/);
        String auth_token_type = settings.getString("tokenType", "");
        String userId = settings.getString("userId", "");

        Log.i("prefs", auth_token_string);


        String url = "https://vitalengine.com/portal-api/api/user/inbox/list?userId=" +
                userId +
                "&folderId=-1&tagId=0&page=1&itemPerPage=1000&showMsgInFolder=false";


        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                .addHeader("Authorization", auth_token_type + " " + auth_token_string)
                .addHeader("user-tz", "-330")
                //.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Log.i(TAG, "call api error");
                Log.e("Volley", e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) {

                try {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful())
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    final String body = response.body().string();


                    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(body);


                    JSONObject sub = Jobject.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray Jarray = sub.getJSONArray("inboxMsgList");

                    Log.e("Array", String.valueOf(Jarray.length()));

                    arrMessageData = new ArrayList<>();

                    int i = 0;
                    Log.i("Orginal Count ", "All: " + Jarray.length());
                    while (i < Jarray.length()) {

                        // for (i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);


                        MessageData msg3 = new MessageData();
                        msg3.setName((String) object.get("fromUser"));
                        msg3.setMessage((String) object.get("message"));
                        // added null check
                        //if (object.getString("toUser").equals(null))
                            msg3.setToUser(object.getString("toUser"));

                        msg3.setRead((Integer) object.get("isRead"));
                        msg3.setPhotoURL((String) object.get("photo"));


                        if (object.get("messageType").equals("CONVERSATION")) {
                            msg3.setType("conversation");

                            msg3.setSubject((String) object.get("subject"));
                            msg3.setId((Integer) object.get("conversationId"));

                        } else if (object.get("messageType").equals("MESSAGE")) {
                            msg3.setType("message");
                            msg3.setId((Integer) object.get("conversationId"));
                            msg3.setType((String) object.get("messageType"));

                            // added message type referral.
                        } else if (object.get("messageType").equals("REFERRALS")) {
                            msg3.setType("referral");
                            msg3.setPatient((String) object.get("patient"));
                            msg3.setId((Integer) object.get("referralId"));
                        }

                        arrMessageData.add(msg3);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        i++;
                    }
                    Log.i("Expected Count ", "All: " + arrMessageData.size());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new Load().execute(null, null, null);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                adapter = new allRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrMessageData);
                usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                usersListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                pd.dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("TAG", msg.what + " ? ");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`Load` is an `AsyncTask` and is running on the background thread, there is no guarantee that the AsyncTasks's `doBackground()` is finished by the time `refreshLayout.onRefresh()` is called.

Instead, update the refreshLayout in `onPostExecute()` method of `Load` task.